# How to declare variables in for loop? (IDL)

Tags: idl-programming-language

For example,

My files are naming after *00.dat, 01.dat, 02.dat*..., each file contains multiple columns and I use `READCOL` to read them into variables.

```
for i = 0, n-1 do begin
    readcol, string(i, F='(I02)')+'.dat', F='D,D', a0, b0
    readcol, string(i, F='(I02)')+'.dat', F='D,D', a1, b1
    .
    .
    c1 = a1 / a0
    c2 = a2 / a0
    .
    .
    d1 = b1 / b0
    d2 = b2 / b0
    .
    .
endfor
```

This works fine, but I cannot type all the varialbes one by one if there will be, say, one hundred variables.

Therefore, I want to use for loop to generate: **a(i), b(i), c(i), d(i)**. In that sense, the code will look like:

```
for i = 0, n-1 do begin
    readcol, string(i, F='(I02)')+'.dat',F='D,D', a(i), b(i)
endfor

for i = 0, n-1 do begin
    c(i) = a(i) / a(0)
    d(i) = b(i) / b(0)
endfor
```

But this doesn't work, is there any method to declare variables in a for loop and while doing math?

*(I am not a native English speaker. Please let me know If there is anything unclear in my question. Thank you!)*

Comment: Use dictionaries! See this post for an explanation and example that is your exact situation: http://pyaos.johnny-lin.com/?p=755

Answer (score 5):

Nice to see another IDL programmer on StackOverflow!

I think part of the problem is that `READCOL` is expecting simple variable names for
its outputs, and in your second example you're giving it array expressions like
`a(i)` and `b(i)` instead of `a` and `b`.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to replace the 1-dimensional arrays
`a0`, `a1`, `b0`, `b1`, etc. from your first example, with 2-dimensional arrays `a`, `b`,
etc. where each array has dimensions (nfiles, samples_per_file).  So if you know
in advance how many lines will be read from each file, you could do something like this:

```
a=dblarr(n,samples_per_file)
b=dblarr(n,samples_per_file)
; similarly for c, d, etc.

for i = 0, n-1 do begin
    readcol, string(i, F='(I02)')+'.dat',F='D,D', x, y
    a[i,*] = x
    b[i,*] = y
    c[i,*] = x/x[0]
    d[i,*] = y/y[0]
endfor
```

This version passes `READCOL` the simple variable names it's expecting, then copies them
into subarrays of the 2-D variables.

If you don't know in advance how many samples are in each file, you could allocate
the 2-d arrays during the first loop iteration:

```
for i = 0, n-1 do begin
    readcol, string(i, F='(I02)')+'.dat',F='D,D', x, y
    if (i EQ 0) then begin
       samples_per_file = n_elements(x)
       a = dblarr(n, samples_per_file)
       b = dblarr(n, samples_per_file)
       c = dblarr(n, samples_per_file)
       d = dblarr(n, samples_per_file)
    endif
    a[i,*] = x
    b[i,*] = y
    c[i,*] = x/x[0]
    d[i,*] = y/y[0]
endfor
```

Of course, this all assumes that each file contains the same number of samples.  If not,
you'd probably need to change `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` to 1-dimensional arrays of pointers,
then use `PTR_NEW` to allocate memory for each file's data as you read it.

(Note that I've used the square bracket `[]` notation for array indexing, which I find a
bit easier to read than `a(i)`, `b(i)` etc. which can be confused with function calls.)