# Declare variables in for loop for files with different number of samples (IDL)

Tags: idl-programming-language

I would like to do exactly what is explained in the answer by Jim Lewis to the post below (see link) in the case that each file contains a different number of samples. Jim states that this can be done using PTR_NEW. Any ideas how to use PTR_NEW in the loop showed in the answer?

Thanks,
Catia

[How to declare variables in for loop? (IDL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932480/how-to-declare-variables-in-for-loop-idl)

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean something like:

```
a = ptrarr(n)
b = ptrarr(n)
c = ptrarr(n)
d = ptrarr(n)

for i = 0L, n - 1L do begin
  readcol, string(i, F='(I02)') + '.dat', F='D,D', x, y
  a[i] = ptr_new(x)
  b[i] = ptr_new(y)
  c[i] = ptr_new(x/x[0])
  d[i] = ptr_new(y/y[0])
endfor
```

Access like this:

```
for i = 0L, n - 1L do begin
  help, *a[i]
endfor
```

In this example, the size and type of `x` and `y` can vary each iteration.